# Qt5 - setWindowOpacity not working?

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm trying to make a window semi-transparent by using setWindowOpacity(), where I'm guessing I'd have to send a number anywhere from 0.0 to 1.0, yet no matter what the value is, I either get fully visible (1.0) or 50% visible(0.0 - 0.9).

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowOpacity(0.5);
}
```

Opacity at 0.01: http://prntscr.com/3nyz7n

Opacity at 0.99: http://prntscr.com/3nyzlr

I'd like to know if this is a bug of some sort or if it's supposed to be like this. Is there a way around this or an alternative to setWindowOpacity?

Using Qt 5.3, MSVC2013, Win7 x64

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two more pics, just in case:

Opacity at 1.0: http://prntscr.com/3nyzy8

Opacity at 0.0: http://prntscr.com/3nz1p2

Comment: I can confirm it's working for me Qt 5.2 MSVC2010 Win7 x64. If you have other Qt version (e.g.) 4.8x you can try just to confirm it's not Qt related but more on your hardware graphics setting perhaps.

Comment: I should've done a few more tests before posting the question. Turns out the problem lies elsewhere as I just tried using setWindowOpacity on another project and it worked as expected. I still can't determine the source of the issue but at least I know I'm probably looking in the wrong place.